# How can I parse an element's contents before appending it? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, parsing, element

I have an html string I'd like to dump directly into an element.  This html string contains some  tags, and I need to prepend a path to their 'src' attributes.

Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```
// note, htmlString is coming in from an external xml file...
var htmlString = "<img src='img1.jpg'/><br/><img src='img2.jpg'/>";
var imgContainer = $('<div />');
imgContainer.append(htmlString);

var prefix = "some/path/to/img/";
imgContainer.find('img').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).attr('src', prefix + $(el).attr('src'));
});
```

This works, but I'm seeing failed resource loads of the non-prepended path.  Seems as though the browser is attempting to load the images immediately upon creation of the imgContainer element, even though it's not appended to the document.  I'd like to avoid those failed loads.

I suppose I could parse htmlString before appending but it's nice to just $.each() through the element after it's created...

**NOTE:** I've learned through asking this question that creating a jQuery element via `$(htmlString)` immediately causes load attempts on all resources within `htmlString`. So, I have to manipulate `htmlString` in some way before packing it into a jQuery object.

Comment: Try using the original jQuery object in `each()`. Remove `i, el` and replace `$(el)` with `$(this)`. Don't know if this will do something but hey, it's easy to try it out.

Comment: @elclanrs no dice...arguably cleaner code tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to parse the `htmlString` as XML, modify it, and then append it to the DOM.

Something like this (Not sure if [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer) works in all browsers, I think it's `this.xml` in IE):

```
var htmlString = "<img src='img1.jpg'/><br/><img src='img2.jpg'/>",
imgContainer = $('<div />')
xml = $.parseXML('<xml>'+htmlString+'</xml>'), // add `<xml>` because
                                               // XML needs a root element
prefix = "some/path/to/img/",
// needed to convert XML to HTML
sXML = typeof XMLSerializer !== 'undefined' && new XMLSerializer;

$(xml).find('img').each(function(i, el) { // replace the SRC
    $(el).attr('src', prefix + $(el).attr('src'));
});

// Convert XML to HTML
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/829724
htmlString = $(xml).find('xml').contents().map(function(i,v){
    return v.xml || sXML.serializeToString(v);
}).get().join('');

imgContainer.append(htmlString);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/de2dg/3/

Comment: ah thank you for replacing this answer!  i saw it, planned to try it, refreshed, and it was gone....trying now.  ps, is there a way to direct message users in SO/StackExchange?  wanted to ping you about this but couldn't see a way...

Comment: @ericsoco: Unfortunately, you can't message users directly.  The only way is to comment on one of their posts.  I deleted this because I wasn't sure it would work in all browsers (or if it was even correct).  It *should* work in *most* browsers now.

Comment: selected this answer because it leaves the original html intact, while @elclanrs' answer (while also useful) extracts just the <img> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you extract images with a regex from string and use an array to hold the images and append everything at last?

```
var str = '<img src=\'img1.jpg\'/><br/><img src=\'img2.jpg\'/>',
    patt = /\w+\d+\.(jpg|png|gif)+/g, // Probably could be better but works
    imgs = str.match(patt),
    prefix = 'some/path/to/img/',
    output = '';
$.each(imgs, function(i, v){ output += '<img src="'+ prefix + v +'"/>'; }); 
$('<div />').append(output).appendTo('#el');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DmKys/

Comment: because the htmlString has a bunch of other stuff interspersed between the <img>s, and is coming in via an external xml file...

Comment: Then you can use a regex to extract the images path from that string and then iterate the array etc...

Comment: oo that sounds lovely but i'm not great with regex. any tips?

Comment: Wouldn't this strip out all tags that aren't `<img>`?  And what if my image was `.png` (or some other URL)?

Comment: Well I think that's the point, extract just the image. This will extract just the image stripping out the domain etc. I adjusted for gif, png and jpg

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the images directly in the html-input like "hidden" and define it in css with display: none; that it doesn't get drawn firstly.

Then in your each-loop delete this class after changing the source.

EDIT: (finally I know what he means)
change the attribute from src to anything like pre_src and use this attribute in your each-loop to attach a new "src" attribute and delete pre_src after this. [removeAttr()]
So the resource wont be loaded and you can use your each-loop...

Comment: each() must be invoked on a jQuery object; as soon as a jQuery object is created any <img>s within it attempt to load.  so, this won't work either.  but, i see now that that's an unavoidable part of my answer -- i need to parse htmlString before stuffing it into a $().

Comment: pleae express yourself better next time :)

Comment: i'd love to express myself as well as possible.  any tips?  what confused you about my question?  btw, your edit has the same problem as your original suggestion.